In the installed “Layout” on “ViewStub”, the button found via “findViewById” does not work
I set setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_no_connection) for ViewStub, then inflate(), and in onInflate() set the logic of the button which is in content_no_connection. And the button does not respond to clicks.
Code:
public void setRebootIncludeLoad(ViewStub includeLoad) {
    includeLoad.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_no_connection);
    includeLoad.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflate(ViewStub viewStub, View view) {

          AppCompatButton btnRebootInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reboot_internet);
          btnRebootInternet.setFocusable(true);
          btnRebootInternet.setClickable(true);
          btnRebootInternet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                         
               Reboot();
             }
          });
        }
   });

   includeLoad.inflate();
}

Please tell me what the problem may be and how to solve it, thank you! I understand that the matter is that I can not find the button I need, but on the button is color selector with color change when you press, and even the color does not change, the button does not respond at all.

Problem solved, you should have added:
((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
activity.setContentView(view);

in onInflate() before AppCompatButton btnRebootInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reboot_nternet);
